# How to export some classes from android project as jar in android

Tags: android

Hi Have created a android project where it consist of some classes(a.java , b.java, c.java..Now i want to export one class(a.java which uses b.java,c.java internally) as jar file..Currently i am exporting by using eclipse by selecting only a.java class while exporting.

When i try to use this jar in another project ,it is displaying "No class def found " error..If i export all the classes no issue..

My intention is i want to expose only one class from there user can access the methods.

It is like a library and sample app.

Comment: Make sure your project is a Library project (i.e.: set your project as Library)

Answer (score 0):

If you are only exporting a.java as jar, it will not have definitions for b and c.So it will always throw a "No class def found" error.Try exporting the whole project as a jar file.
Exporting as jar will only work if you do not have any resources attached to the code(ids,layouts etc), in such a case use android library project.

Comment: If i export total project as jar,then user(who is trying to use the library can see all the classes which are there in that jar and he can create the instance of any class.my intention is i don't want to allow the user to create instance of all the classes instead he can create only one class instance.